# Displaying the rest of a list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, pagination

This could be a pagination question, but I'm not sure how to title it.

I have a list of `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12....]`

I'd like to display the list at first as `[1,2,3]`

Then with a click of a button it will give the next 3 and so on

obivously the list doesn't have to be numbers it could users like in twitter, statuses in facebook, email headers, pictures and so on but the concept remains the same

How would I implement this?

Comment: Why not use one of the many available pagination plugins? You already indicate it is a pagination problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the gem [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). You can do something like the following:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

And paginate generic objects. There is a paragraph about that in the README.

Answer (score 1):

```
> number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
> number[0..2]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```